# Facebook Page for business without admin account, can't use old Shared Login

Tags: facebook

I was recently hired to act as social media advisor for a very small firm. The Facebook page was supposedly under control of a Facebook account that used shared login (both Facebook and Gmail) details.

Facebook deactivated shared accounts some time ago, but it also looks like they disabled the upgrade path for shared accounts to become viable accounts - none of the buttons or links on the Facebook site work, *not even deleting the account will work*. They will redirect to a page I make with the account, or if no page exists, the homepage for Facebook business. I managed to contact Facebook somehow several weeks ago, but clicking "support inbox" redirects to the page.

According to the one active Editor, there is **no admin listed on the page**.

When I try to add the old account to the new business manager, it won't let me, and tells me to upgrade the shared account with a dead link that just redirects to business.facebook.com

I ended up making a new account, but with no way to delete the old one - what do I do?

Comment: Report it to Facebook and ask them to delete it.

Comment: The plan is to mass-report the old account, but I was hoping for something more...definite.